# Trouble analyzing amine using GC-FID

Tags: organic-chemistry, analytical-chemistry, chromatography

I am trying to analyze a sample containing hexamethylenediamine (HMD) dissolved in ethanol using GC-FID for an undergraduate chemical engineering project. The column used is Agilent DB-FFAP (high polarity). The program used was 95°C (hold for 6 min) followed by 7°C/min increase until 235°C (hold for 2 mins). Different concentrations of HMD were used, the highest being 0.1g/ml however none of the chromatograms showed peaks for HMD. There was always only one peak in each chromatogram. This was attributed to the solvent (ethanol).

Are there any potential solutions to this problem? Is the problem with the type of column used? Should higher sample concentrations be used? Thanks in advance.

Comment: For readers: *Agilent J&W DB-FFAP is a nitroterephthalic-acid-modified polyethylene glycol (PEG) column of high polarity for the analysis of volatile fatty acids and phenols. It is a close equivalent to USP phase G35 and replaces OV-351.*

Comment: It may matter the analyte is basic amine and not an acid or phenol. It may sit on column, being eluted too slowly.

Comment: First of all, run the column QC experiment under identical conditions. If you can nearly reproduce the chromatogram, then everything is working fine. Otherwise, you will have to consult someone experienced in GC in your academic department. Amines are a classic example of compounds which interact very strongly with any silica based column in both liquid, gas and subcritical fluid chromatography. One should not run free amines in GC.

Comment: Silanols are acidic and amines are basic. You will have to quantitatively derivative them to amides or some other inactive group. As some said "An hour spent in the library is worth a month in the laboratory", so start with a literature search and find a reagent that is used to convert amines to something for GC purposes.